# Set default icon when specified path does not exist

Tags: inno-setup

I have a Inno Setup script with different `#define` that I enable individually in order to compile setups for different clients.

In the **[Setup]** section I set the `WizardImageFile` property as

```
WizardImageFile={#CustomClientResourceFolder}\logo.bmp
```

Now, the problem is that I do not have this "logo.bmp" for every client, and I wish not to create fake "logo.bmp" with default images. But if I compile the code above without the image, the compiler throws a "Missing file" error.

**So:**
How could I tell Inno Setup something like "use this logo.bmp and if you don't find it use your default setup icons"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conditionally use the `WizardImageFile` directive, only if the file exists. Use [`#ifexist` preprocessor directive](https://jrsoftware.org/ispphelp/index.php?topic=ifdef):

```
#define LogoPath CustomClientResourceFolder + "\logo.bmp"

#ifexist LogoPath
WizardImageFile={#LogoPath}
#endif
```

Comment: Never heard of "#ifexist" directive, quite useful! Perfect, thank you very much!